# How to save hardened fondant?

Tags: storage-method, fondant

I make cakes with fondant decorations and figurines. To harden the fondant for these figurines, I add [tylose or CMC powder](http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-tylose-powder). Sometimes, I just color the white fondant to get the desired color without tylose. Once done, I store this fondant by rolling into balls and wrapping in cling wrap before storing in an air tight container, so that air does not get to the fondant and harden it. However, after a few months, when I open the box, I find that the fondant has harden and I can't use it anymore and end up throwing all that fondant.

Can someone please suggest:

1. How to store fondant better?
2. How to soften the hardened fondant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often soften Fondant by microwaving it for between 5-20 seconds. This does work on fondant that hasn't been left for more than 2 months. Once fondant has been left for this long, albeit in an airtight container, it isn't likely to be salvageable.

Most manufacturers of fondant [quote](http://www.wilton.com/decorating/fondant/fondant-storage-chart.cfm) 2 months as the lifetime of fondant stored in an airtight container.

Comment: I tried that with some of the fondant and even though it looks like it might soften up, it gets hard and dry and "unkneadable" very quickly. I would hate to throw away all that fondant :(